# I have a static page linked to a directory of images and am trying to make a version that links to an individual image instead

Tags: html, image

I have a static html page created that links to a folder of images, which get called out depending on the url address entered.  The problem is that I need an static page linked to only one specific image, so that I can give that html file to clients.  I am only trying to change one line (the first line) of a specific section of code relevant to the image being summoned.

The section of code I have that works for the folder of images is:

```
var filepath = 'https://domain.com/folder/subfolder/'+getQueryVariable("image");
        var currentSphere = new THREE.Mesh(
            new THREE.SphereGeometry(100, 32, 32),
            new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(filepath)
            })
```

What I tried to change it to is:

```
var filepath = 'https://domain.com/folder/subfolder/example.jpg';
        var currentSphere = new THREE.Mesh(
            new THREE.SphereGeometry(100, 32, 32),
            new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(filepath)
            })
```

But when I do that, nothing appears.  The first code works flawlessly, but I need to figure out how to link to an individual image.  I thought that my change would work, but it does not.  What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Thanks,
NM

Comment: What does the typical `getQueryVariable` look like?

Comment: example.jpg exists, it is one of the images I link to normally through: www.domain.com/index.html?image=example.jpg

if an image doesn't exist, I get a black screen, with the buttons I have set up displaying properly, which is what keeps happening when I try linking to example.jpg directly

Comment: the getQueryVariable looks like the end of this url: www.domain.com/index.html?image=example.jpg

It is case sensitive, but I have been careful to enter the image name exactly

Comment: So, the code is looking for a query string.  Try `?image=example.jpg` as your hard coded version

Comment: I'm hoping to remove the getQueryVariable altogether for this version, it should be unnecessary if I'm calling out a specific image